# Changing font color of string in vb

Tags: vb.net

How can I change font color of a string. I set the fore color properties of the label holding the string but seems that only works when the string is displayed in that label. Is there a way of setting the color of a string itself such that it displays any where with that color by default. I am actually sending this string as email but wanted to format it in a way that it will display differently however it doesn't. Any ideas

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WebForms, or something else entirely? Is the text displayed in a TextBox control?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to set this in a property of a string. However, you might be able to make the information part of the text of the string itself via html:

```
<font color="red">The rest of your string goes here</font>
```